# Why taking location can't be done in a bling of an eye?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

When accessing locationManager.location, why it takes more than a blink of an eye?

[image]

Basically I am accessing [CLLocationHandler currentLocation] Why I have mach_msg_trap showing up as if it's waiting for something. Wait for what?

I am not asking to get the next updated location. I am asking for the last updated location.

Comment: You do know you have an active breakpoint on line 143...

Comment: I know and that's not the problem. The code there will only be executed when things go really wrong. I ended up catching the location for 60 seconds and that sort of solve it.